# How to pass an attribute of a java object from a jsp page to a servlet on clicking an image button?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I am retrieving a list of image objects from database on a JSP page in a table format. I have to perform delete operation on an image for which I'll need the image id. Delete will be performed on click of an image button. How can I pass the id of the image clicked to the servlet in which I'm deleting the image from the database.
Here is the code I'm trying :

```
<% 
    for (Image image : images) 
   {
        double imageSizeInKB = image.getImageSize()/1000.0;
        int imageId = image.getId();
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=serialNumber%></td>
        <td><%=image.getImageName()%></td>
        <td><%=imageSizeInKB%></td>
        <td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<%=image.getBase64Image() %>" width="200" height="200"/></td>
        <td><img id="edit" width="40" height="40" src="Images/edit.png"/>
        <form action="delete" method="post">
           <input type="image" onClick= "<%  session.setAttribute("imageId",image.getId()); %>" src="Images/delete.png" name="submit" width="40" height="40" alt="submit"/>
         </form> </td>
    </tr>

<%
  serialNumber++;
} 
%>
```

Comment: Just add your `id` as a hidden field in your HTML form.  When you POST it will get POSTED too.

Comment: Also do yourself a favour and use JSTL